# How do I view the signature of an iOS application?

Tags: appsec, openssl, macos, iphone

OSX [had an issue where the certificate was expired](http://techcrunch.com/2015/11/12/all-mac-store-apps-stopped-working-due-to-expired-security-certificate) and several apps could not be opened after that date.

[image]

The command above illustrates how this could have been detected.

Does iOS have a similar expiration?  How can I inspect or view it?

Comment: I know for sure that it does have an expiration because one of my company's apps unexpectedly quit working.  Turns out no one was paying attention to/updating the validity date.  Caused a whole lot of hell with our customers for 2 days.

Comment: As iOS apps are controlled through the Apple app store, I would guess that there is no need for a separate certificate to prove they are genuine.  Apple will remove apps from developers who do not maintain status with them.  OSX is different because there are distribution channels other than Apple for third party apps.  In briefly looking about on the Apple Developer sites, I did not find any mention of certificates as above.  I also have had an iPhone for 5 years and have never once had an app quit on me...